# Multiple scenario on sticky position

Tags: html, css, css-position, sticky

I am getting the same issue while using the sticky position.

For example

1) The first scenario, Sticky position is working in this scenario.

```
<div class=">
<div class="">sticky position</div>
<div class="">some content</div>
</div>
```

2) Secondary scenario, Sticky position is not working in this because I added the parent div. So is there any other way to handle this issue with a parent class of the sticky div?

```
<div class=">
      <div class=""><div class="">sticky position</div></div>
      <div class="">some content</div>
</div>
```

3) The third scenario, If the sticky position is in the first section which is working for the only first section. What if need same sticky position on the second section?

```
<section>
<div class="">sticky position</div>
<div class="">some content</div>
</section>

<section>
<div class="">some content</div>
</section>
```

I tried first two senario

**First senario**

```css
.positionSticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="positionSticky"></div>
  <div>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nibh, faucibus tristique massa sapien
      sed augue. Quisque eros sapien, facilisis ac magna a, interdum ornare nulla. </p>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nibh, faucibus tristique massa sapien
      sed augue. Quisque eros sapien, facilisis ac magna a, interdum ornare nulla. </p>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Second senario**

```css
.positionSticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="positionSticky"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nibh, faucibus tristique massa sapien
      sed augue. Quisque eros sapien, facilisis ac magna a, interdum ornare nulla. </p>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nibh, faucibus tristique massa sapien
      sed augue. Quisque eros sapien, facilisis ac magna a, interdum ornare nulla. </p>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

After using @Jake answer

```css
#height_100vh {
  height: 100vh;
}

.positionSticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.ps-dad {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<section id="height_100vh">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="ps-dad">
      <div class="positionSticky"></div>
    </div>


    <div>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nibh, faucibus tristique massa
        sapien sed augue. Quisque eros sapien, facilisis ac magna a, interdum ornare nulla. </p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>


    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nibh, faucibus tristique massa
        sapien sed augue. Quisque eros sapien, facilisis ac magna a, interdum ornare nulla. </p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nibh, faucibus tristique massa
        sapien sed augue. Quisque eros sapien, facilisis ac magna a, interdum ornare nulla. </p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nibh, faucibus tristique massa
        sapien sed augue. Quisque eros sapien, facilisis ac magna a, interdum ornare nulla. </p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The First scenario is working. I need to solve the second scenario and third scenario. 
Would you help me out in this?

Comment: Why can't you move the sticky div outside of the section ? Sticky works relative to its parent. The only way you could solve it would be to use `position: fixed`

Comment: Hey @questionbank, what's the status on your issue ? Is it fixed ?

Comment: @Jake, no my issue not resolved till now. So I change the UI but I have to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First solution : set the parent of all your `div`s (.container) to `display: flex`:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.positionSticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="positionSticky"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nibh, faucibus tristique massa sapien
      sed augue. Quisque eros sapien, facilisis ac magna a, interdum ornare nulla. </p>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nibh, faucibus tristique massa sapien
      sed augue. Quisque eros sapien, facilisis ac magna a, interdum ornare nulla. </p>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Second solution: set the parent of `.positionSticky` to `display: inline;`

```css
.ps-dad {
    display: inline;
}

.positionSticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ps-dad">
    <div class="positionSticky"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nibh, faucibus tristique massa sapien
      sed augue. Quisque eros sapien, facilisis ac magna a, interdum ornare nulla. </p>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nibh, faucibus tristique massa sapien
      sed augue. Quisque eros sapien, facilisis ac magna a, interdum ornare nulla. </p>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit, tellus
      vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci id libero.
      Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum laoreet
      tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Third solution: set `.positionSticky` to `position: fixed;` instead of `sticky`

```css
#height_100vh {
    height: 100vh;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.positionSticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section id="height_100vh">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="ps-dad">
      <div class="positionSticky"></div>
    </div>


    <div>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nibh, faucibus tristique massa
        sapien sed augue. Quisque eros sapien, facilisis ac magna a, interdum ornare nulla. </p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>


    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nibh, faucibus tristique massa
        sapien sed augue. Quisque eros sapien, facilisis ac magna a, interdum ornare nulla. </p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nibh, faucibus tristique massa
        sapien sed augue. Quisque eros sapien, facilisis ac magna a, interdum ornare nulla. </p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nibh, faucibus tristique massa
        sapien sed augue. Quisque eros sapien, facilisis ac magna a, interdum ornare nulla. </p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem ut ex egestas, vitae interdum metus imperdiet. Integer finibus, urna quis rutrum pretium, leo leo sodales nib</p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel dui tempor, maximus quam eu, molestie velit. Curabitur porttitor mollis velit in suscipit. Phasellus elit leo, posuere ut est eu, fringilla aliquet tortor. Aenean blandit,
        tellus vitae mollis vulputate, risus erat pulvinar dui, eget pulvinar eros libero non ex. Quisque mauris ex, placerat et laoreet a, tincidunt a ipsum. Nam convallis, ante ut porta luctus, arcu ligula consequat orci, scelerisque porta magna orci
        id libero. Praesent a mi ut quam dapibus dignissim. Quisque commodo eu magna et bibendum. In pharetra dui et pretium lobortis. In mauris nisi, feugiat quis mi id, molestie mattis quam. In hendrerit vel erat ut malesuada. Fusce magna eros, condimentum
        laoreet tincidunt eget, luctus eget odio. Integer pellentesque ornare lacus eget sagittis. Nullam semper lorem</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: I tried your solution but It's working but not 100%. I added a snippet in the code. Please check it and assist me where I am wrong. I have to display the red box until the end.

Comment: Edited my answer with a third solution using `position: fixed`. See [this article](https://medium.com/@elad/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46) to understand how sticky works. Right now, it is limited by the height of your section and unless you change your markup it will not be able to go beyond.

Comment: The reason is not to use fixed because of my red box is going backside at the end of the footer that's the reason I am using sticky.

Comment: If you can't move your `.positionSticky` `div` outside of `section` and into the main container you won't be able to use `position: sticky`. You could use `position: fixed` and add some JS that modifies top and bottom values on scroll once it reaches the footer.